# Should it be 'было' or 'были' in this case?

Tags: грамматика

What option is correct?

> Его уникальным изобразительным средством был**о** всего три символа.

or

> Его уникальным изобразительным средством был**и** всего три символа.

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is stylistic, and I don't think there is enough context to choose the best style unequivocally.

Rosenthal's guide has a whole chapter about this, with these two rules which are most relevant to your case:

> - §189. Согласование связки не с подлежащим, а с именной частью составного сказуемого (так называемое обратное согласование) чаще всего встречается в следующих случаях: … при наличии в составе подлежащего имени существительного собирательного с количественным значением, например: *Большая часть между ними были довольно добрые люди (Герцен) (ср. §183, п. 3. подпункт 6); Большинство участников выставки были люди приезжие*
>   При подлежащем, имеющем в своем составе собирательное существительное с количественным значением (большинство, меньшинство, ряд, часть и др.), сказуемое может стоять в единственном числе (грамматическое согласование) и во множественном числе (согласование по смыслу).
> - §184.5. При числительных *два, три, четыре, двое, трое, четверо* сказуемое обычно ставится в форме множественного числа, например: *Два солдата с котомками равнодушно глядели на окна поезда… (А.Н. Толстой); Тридцать два человека… дышали одним духом (Шолохов); Двое рабочих в белых фартуках копались около дома (Чехов).* Но сказуемые-глаголы со значением бытия, наличия, существования, положения в пространстве и т.д. (т.е. со значением состояния, а не действия) обычно в этих случаях употребляются в форме единственного числа, например: *Три царства перед ней стояло (Некрасов); …При больнице состояло два человека (Тургенев); Умерло от удара… еще три человека (Л.Толстой); У него было два сына (Чехов); В комнате было два окна с широкими подоконниками (Каверин); Может быть две смелости: одна – привитая воспитанием, другая – врожденное свойство характера (В.Панова).*

If I were to assume that each of these symbols is used as an art medium separately from the others, and the text further elaborates on each of these three symbols, I would use the plural.

If the medium is the three symbols as a whole, I would go with the singular.

Comment: Thank you! Very informative.